# Postgres escape a single quote

Tags: postgresql, escaping, quotes, amazon-redshift

I have the following postgres query:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) 
FROM DB
WHERE ID NOT IN (<parameter>)
```

`<parameter>` is a dynamic text field where multiple ID's need to be inserted. If you type in

> 123, 456

as ID's, it results in:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) 
FROM DB
WHERE ID NOT IN ('123,456')
```

Which doesn't run properly.

I can change the query, but I can't change the input field. If you type in

> 123','456

It results in:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) 
FROM DB
WHERE ID NOT IN ('123'',''456')
```

When you change the query into:

> ```
> SELECT SUM(Cost) 
> FROM DB
> WHERE ID NOT IN ('<parameter>')
> ```

And you type in

> 123,456
>   Then it results in:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) 
FROM DB
WHERE ID NOT IN (''123'',''456'')
```

I've got it working for Mysql, but not for Postgresql. Any idea how to trick postgresql?

Comment: What is the language you are using to pass the parameter? The parameter must be passed as an array in PHP and as a tuple/list in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) 
FROM DB
WHERE ID != ALL(('{'||'123,456'||'}')::numeric[])
```

It will form array string from your input values : `{123,456}`, cast it to an array and check ID against all elements of array.